Is there a way to create a #define depending on the executable that calls the file?
I have a class that is used by 2 executables that operate completely separately.  In one executable, I would like my class function to ignore an 'if' statement. I could do it by passing an argument to my object but that seems terrible. Is there a way to create a definition (#define, cmake's add_definitions, etc) based on the target that compiled it?

You can pass an option to your compiler that translates into a #define in your code. Is that what you mean?

Why not just use add_definition in cmake, which you already mentioned, for whatever target needs the special behavior?  If the file in the sources for each executable, it'll be compiled twice already.

The preprocessor and macros and #define are compile-time only. You could build the two programs with a common macro set to a different value for each program, e.g. -DPROGRAM_SELECTOR=1 for the first, and -DPROGRAM_SELECTOR=2 for the second. With that said, I don't think that it will be a good solution to whatever problem you're trying to solve. What will be a better solution depends quite a lot on the actual and underlying problem you need to solve.

Macros are expanded at compile time, which usually is before runtime.  Do the two executables in question each compile your class, or are you contemplating compiling it separately for each executable?  Otherwise, nothing macro-based would be suitable.

"I could do it by passing an argumeent to my object but that seems terible" -- why? Modulating the behavior of your classes and functions is exactly the purpose of constructor and function parameters. Perhaps it would help to couch the problem in terms different from making the function "ignore an if statement", focusing instead on client-observable differences in behavior.

The solution most suggested is the same I thought of: adding definitions for each target. I did not go this route, hoping there was a clever or obvious solution for this, but it seems it is not a common workaround. I restrained myself from adding a macro directly in the executable flags because, in my opinion, it makes the executable call more confusing and unnecessarily large. It is, anyway, a workaround and something that won’t be permanent but useful in debugging and testing. That is why I didn’t bother with details.

Could you explain your question in more detail and clarity?
As far as I understand it can be done like this.
CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)
project(example)

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Weffc++)
endif()

add_executable(program_1 program_1.cpp my_class.hpp)
add_executable(program_2 program_2.cpp my_class.hpp)

target_compile_definitions(program_1 PRIVATE CONTROL_FLAG=1)
target_compile_definitions(program_2 PRIVATE CONTROL_FLAG=0)

program_1.cpp
#include "my_class.hpp"

int main([[maybe_unused]]int argc , [[maybe_unused]] char** argv)
{
    MyClass my_class(10);
    my_class.echoDisplay();
    return 0;
}

program_2.cpp
#include "my_class.hpp"

int main([[maybe_unused]]int argc , [[maybe_unused]] char** argv)
{
    MyClass my_class(10);
    my_class.echoDisplay();
    return 0;
}

my_class.hpp
#ifndef __MY_CLASS_HPP__
#define __MY_CLASS_HPP__

#include <iostream>

#ifndef CONTROL_FLAG
#define CONTROL_FLAG 0
#endif

class MyClass
{
private:
    int a;

public:
    MyClass(int a) : a{a} {}
    int getA() const { return this->a; }
    void setA(int a) { this->a = a; }
    void echoDisplay()
    {
        if (CONTROL_FLAG)
        {
            std::cout << "Hello World." << std::endl;
        }

        std::cout << "a: " << getA() << std::endl;
    }
};

#endif


Build

cmake -B build
cmake --build build


Run

./program_1

# Output
Hello World.
a: 10

./program_2

# Output
a: 10

or You can also do this with a makefile.
makefile
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Weffc++

BUILD_DIR = build

SRCS = my_class.hpp
PROG1 = $(BUILD_DIR)/program_1
PROG2 = $(BUILD_DIR)/program_2

.PHONY: all
all: $(BUILD_DIR) $(PROG1) $(PROG2)

$(BUILD_DIR):
    @mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR)

$(PROG1): $(SRCS) program_1.cpp
    @$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -DCONTROL_FLAG=1 -o $@ $^

$(PROG2): $(SRCS) program_2.cpp
    @$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -DCONTROL_FLAG=0 -o $@ $^

run: 
    @echo "_____________________"
    @echo "Running $(PROG1):"
    @./$(PROG1)
    @echo "_____________________"
    @echo "Running $(PROG2):"
    @./$(PROG2)

.PHONY: update_bashrc
clean:
    @rm -rf $(BUILD_DIR)


Build

make


Run

make run

# Output
Running build/program_1:
Hello World.
a: 10
_____________________
Running build/program_2:
a: 10

Note:
The easiest way is to define this at the top of the executables you call without having to mess with the makefile or cmake. This way it will work the same way since it runs before the library.

program_1.cpp

#define CONTROL_FLAG 1

#include "my_class.hpp"

int main([[maybe_unused]]int argc , [[maybe_unused]] char** argv)
{
    MyClass my_class(10);
    my_class.echoDisplay();
    return 0;
}


program_2.cpp

#define CONTROL_FLAG 0

#include "my_class.hpp"

int main([[maybe_unused]]int argc , [[maybe_unused]] char** argv)
{
    MyClass my_class(10);
    my_class.echoDisplay();
    return 0;
}


Minor: the preprocessor include guard you use (__MY_CLASS_HPP__) is a reserved identifier. It's undefined behaviour per 20.5.4.3 Reserved names [reserved.names] (C++17 numbering), but will (most likely) work in practice.

@Erel Yes, you are right, but this is just a simple exercise as an example.

When you define main as int main(int argc, char **argv), argv[0] is the name of the command that was used to run the program. Your operating system should have system calls that will resolve any symlinks and relative paths, and extract the base name of the file. You can then set a flag based on that and use it to branch however you choose.
(This assumes that by "two executables", you mean two different files, not just two different processes. If they don't have separate names, you probably want to have them talk to each other over a TCP connection or something on startup and negotiate a unique ID for each copy of the process, which you can then condition on. Some multiprocessing libraries, like MPI, will do this automatically.)

Supposing your 2 executables have different names, you could do something like this in your class constructor. It even should work if the class is used in a separate .dll file.
    std::string file_name = __argv[0];
    std::string::size_type slash = file_name.find_last_of("/\\");
    if (slash == std::string::npos) {
        exe_name = file_name;
    } else {
        exe_name = std::string(file_name.begin() + slash + 1, file_name.end());
    }
    // set a (bool?) value to ignore your "if" depending on exe_name

